# Expectation and variance of dice throwing game.

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, dice

You roll a die, if the number on the die is higher than 2 you roll the first die again. Otherwise, you roll a second die, if the number on the second die is greater than 5 you get 1 point, if the number on the second die is less than or equal to 5 you get 2 points. What is the expected value and variance of the game if the game is played a large number of times.

What I've tried so far:

Let $X$ be the event that you roll higher than 5 on the second die and let $Y$ be the event that you roll less than or equal to 5 on the second die. Since the probability of rolling higher than 2 is $\frac{4}{6}$ and less than or equal to 2 is $\frac{2}{6}$ for the first die, I think the expected value of the game would be: $$\frac{2}{6}\cdot E(X) + \frac{4}{6}\cdot E(Y).$$

I think $E(X) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot1 = \frac{1}{6}$ and $E(Y) = \frac{5}{6}\cdot 2 = \frac{5}{3}$ which would give an expected value of the game of $\frac{7}{6}$. However, I am not confident at all that this is correct or even on the right lines and I don't know how to get the variance at all, I also don't know how to factor in the statment: "if the game is played a large number of times".

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: So what happens to the first die? If you get, say $1$ on the first die, then you roll again. Does it stop there? Or is it if you get $1$ and then $5$, then you roll the second die? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Good point it's actually not that clear to me either. I think it's If you get <=2 on the first die, you would then roll the second die once and that would be one iteration of the game, you would get either 0, 1 or 2 points per iteration of the game. So you only roll the second die once if you get <=2 on the first die. If you get >2 on the first die, you roll the first die again, if you get >2 again you'd get zero for that iteration of the game. Then you'd roll the first die again for the next iteration of the game, and you'd carry on like this "for a large number of times".

Answer (score 1):

As clarified in your comment, the number of points you get in a single iteration of the game can be $\ 0,1\ $ or $\ 2\ $. The first occurs if you roll $\ 3\ $ or more with the first die, which happens with probability $\ \frac{2}{3}\ $.  You get $\ 1\ $ point if you throw $\ 2\ $ or less with the first die and then $\ 6\ $ with the second, which happens with probability $\   \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{18} $. You get $\ 2\ $ points if you throw $\ 2\ $ or less with the first die and then $\ 5\ $ or less with the second, which happens with probability $\  \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{5}{6}=\frac{5}{18} $.  Your expected score is therefore
$$
E(P)=0\cdot\frac{2}{3}+1\cdot\frac{1}{18}+2\cdot\frac{5}{18}= \frac{11}{18}\ ,
$$
where $\ P\ $ is the random variable representing the number of points you get in a single iteration of the game.  The easiest way to get the variance is to use the identity
$$
\text{var}(P)=E(P^2)-E(P)^2\ .
$$
You can work out $\ E(P^2)\ $ in essentially the same way as you work out $\ E(P)\ $, except that you replace the possible values of $\ P\ $ in the formula with their squares.